# Install Cinnamon on openSUSE

Tags: x11, opensuse, desktop-environment, cinnamon, display-manager

I would like to install Cinnamon on my openSUSE 13.1 minimal installation. But I've the following Problem. I add the repo install it from Yast/Zypper.

```
sudo zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:/Cinnamon:/Factory/openSUSE_13.1 Cinnamon
sudo zypper ref Cinnamon
yast/zypper in -t pattern Cinnamon
```

My Problem is that X11 isn't in the dependencies so I've to install the pattern manually. I've done that but how can I start Cinnamon now? When I try to execute `startx` it says that `startx` isn't installed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get "startx" by installing xinit:

```
$ zypper install xinit
```

Then make sure xinit is configured in your $HOME/.xinitrc so that startx loads cinnamon. Something like this:

.xinitrc:

```
#!/bin/sh
#exec gnome-session
exec gnome-session –session=cinnamon
```

Make the ‘.xinitrc’ file executable.

```
$ chmod a+x .xinitrc
```

You can next time figure it out by searching:

```
$ zypper search --provides /usr/bin/startx
```

Or by using the "command not found" utility, which I will skip here.

Alternatively, you can start the full graphical login manager:

```
$ systemctl start xdm.service
```

Or You can start the target instead of the service only:

```
$ systemctl list-units --type=target
UNIT                 LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
basic.target         loaded active active Basic System
...
graphical.target     loaded active active Graphical Interface
...
```

Then

$ systemctl start graphical.target

**If you use the login manager, you should be able to select Cinnamon from the session list.**

You can use "status" instead of start to see why it failed in case X does not start.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now something starts but I'm pretty sure that it isn't cinnamon. I get a grey background with a small shell which looks like it was used about 20 years ago :-). Do I've to change the default DE somewhere?

Comment: I updated the answer with instructions on how to configure the session in both the xinit and the login manager methods.